# how to specify column as a range in a excel macro

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a macro to compare two columns and if value are equal then it should copy value of another cell into a new cell. I wrote below macro:

```
Sub Value()

   Dim rng1 As Range
   Set rng1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("L2:L11860")
   Dim rng2 As Range
   Set rng2 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("W2:W12000")
   Dim rng3 As Range
   Set rng3 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A12000")
   Dim rng4 As Range
   Set rng4 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("X2:X12000")

If rng1.Value = rng2.Value Then

rng3.Value = rng4.Value


 End If

End Sub
```

It is giving me `Run Time error 13` for the below line of code

```
If rng1.Value = rng2.Value Then
```

Please help in solving this.

Comment: Are you trying to do an all or nothing?  ie.  if the whole column is equal then do what you want or do you want to compare row by row?

Comment: You can't compare more than 1 cell with more than 1 cell. Try a `for` loop that increments by the row.

Comment: To specify an entire column the notation would be `A:A`. BUT as findwindow says, you can't compare an entire column to another with one compare.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it without loops:

```
Sub Value()

Dim rng1 As Range
Set rng1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("L2:L12000")

Dim rng2 As Range
Set rng2 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("W2:W12000")

Dim rng3 As Range
Set rng3 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A12000")

Dim rng4 As Range
Set rng4 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("X2:X12000")

rng3.Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Evaluate("=IF(INDEX(" & rng1.Address(0, 0) & "=" & rng2.Address(0, 0) & ",)," & rng4.Address(0, 0) & ","""")")


End Sub
```

---

Or as Dirk Suggested you could just:

```
Sub Value()

Dim rng1 As Range
Set rng1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("L2:L12000")

Dim rng2 As Range
Set rng2 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("W2:W12000")

Dim rng3 As Range
Set rng3 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A12000")

Dim rng4 As Range
Set rng4 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("X2:X12000")

rng3.Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Evaluate("=IF(" & rng1.Address(0, 0) & "=" & rng2.Address(0, 0) & "," & rng4.Address(0, 0) & ","""")")


End Sub
```

Comment: Just as a hint: also `rng3.Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Evaluate("=IF(" & rng1.Address & "=" & rng2.Address & "," & rng4.Address & "," & rng3.Address & ")")` will do... no need for index (and range 3 will not be overwritten), but that ist to be used as needed ;)